# Select using MemberQ

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I want to make a selection on this list

```
words = {{{"word1", "word2"}, 19}, {{"word1", "word3"}, 
   8}, {{"word1", "word4"}, 7}, {{"word2", "word5"}, 
   7}, {{"word2", "word5"}, 7}, {{"word3", "word6"}, 
   7}, {{"word3", "word7"}, 7}, {{"word3", "word8"}, 
   6}, {{"word4", "word6"}, 6}};
```

From this list, I want to select all 'records' which have one of these words

```
wordsselect = {"word2", "word4", "word8"}
```

The desirde output is:

```
wordsnew = {{{"word1", "word2"}, 19}, {{"word1", "word4"}, 
   7}, {{"word2", "word5"}, 7}, {{"word2", "word5"}, 
   7}, {{"word3", "word8"}, 6}, {{"word4", "word6"}, 6}}
```

I tried to make a selection based on one word

```
Select[words[[All, {1, 2}]], MemberQ[#[[1]], "word2"] &]
```

this works fine. So I tried the next script

```
Select[words[[All, {1, 2}]], MemberQ[#[[1]], wordsselect ] &]
```

The output is empty {}

I have two questions:

1. How do I get the desired output?
2. Why is my second try not working?

Comment: Try Alternatives@@wordsselect instead. This will be a real pattern involving alternatives. Your pattern matches with any list that exactly equals the list of three words.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already noted the second argument of `MemberQ` needs to be a pattern or literal expression; [`Alternatives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alternatives.html) can be used here.

Another method is to use [`IntersectingQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntersectingQ.html) instead:

```
Select[words, IntersectingQ[#[[1]], wordsselect] &]
```

> ```
> {{{"word1", "word2"}, 19}, {{"word1", "word4"}, 7},
>  {{"word2", "word5"}, 7}, {{"word2", "word5"}, 7},
>  {{"word3", "word8"}, 6}, {{"word4", "word6"}, 6}}
> ```

Comment: thank you again finding yet another useful function I was not aware of: `IntersectingQ`...my blindspot seems ever increasing as my time is ever decreasing...+1 :)

Answer (score 3):

```
Select[words, MemberQ[#[[1]], "word1" | "word2" | "word8"] &]
```

Answer (score 3):

1. This one should work:

`Select[words, Or @@ (MemberQ[wordsselect, #] & /@ #[[1]]) &]`

It checks for each one of the words in the first list-element. If there is at least one word in the `wordsselect` list then the whole element is selected.

2. With `MemberQ[#[[1]], wordsselect ] &` you are checking if the list `wordsselect` is inside each {"wordX","wordY"}

Answer (score 3):

Just for something different:

```
Flatten[Last@Reap[Sow[{##}, #1] & @@@ words, wordsselect, #2 &], 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
words =
  {{{"w1", "w2"}, 19}, {{"w1", "w3"}, 8}, {{"w1", "w4"}, 7}, 
  {{"w2", "w5"}, 7}, {{"w2", "w5"}, 7}, {{"w3", "w6"}, 7},
  {{"w3", "w7"}, 7}, {{"w3", "w8"}, 6}, {{"w4", "w6"}, 6}};

keys = {"w2", "w4", "w8"};
```

Using `ContainsAny` (new in 10.2)

```
Select[words, ContainsAny[#[[1]], keys] &]
```

{{{"w1", "w2"}, 19}, {{"w1", "w4"}, 7}, {{"w2", "w5"},
7}, {{"w2", "w5"}, 7}, {{"w3", "w8"}, 6}, {{"w4", "w6"}, 6}}

Two other possibilities:

```
Pick[words, ContainsAny[keys] /@ First /@ words];

Cases[words, {{a_, b_}, _} /; MemberQ[keys, a | b]];
```

Answer (score 2):

Pre v10 without `IntersectingQ` you can do this:

```
 Select[words, Length@Intersection[#[[1]], wordsselect] > 0 &]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `ReplaceAll` and `MemberQ`:

```
words = {{{"word1", "word2"}, 19}, {{"word1", "word3"}, 8}, 
         {{"word1", "word4"}, 7}, {{"word2", "word5"}, 7}, 
         {{"word2", "word5"}, 7}, {{"word3", "word6"}, 7}, 
         {{"word3", "word7"}, 7}, {{"word3", "word8"}, 6},
         {{"word4", "word6"}, 6}};

keys = {"word2", "word4", "word8"};

wordsnew = {{{"word1", "word2"}, 19}, {{"word1", "word4"}, 7}, 
            {{"word2", "word5"}, 7}, {{"word2", "word5"}, 7}, 
            {{"word3", "word8"}, 6}, {{"word4", "word6"}, 6}};

words /. {x : {__}, y_} /; ! MemberQ[keys, Alternatives @@ x] :> Nothing

% === wordsnew

(*True*)
```

Or using `ReplaceAll` and `IntersectingQ`:

```
words /. {x : {__}, y_} /; ! IntersectingQ[keys, x] :> Nothing

% === wordsnew

(*True*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some variations:

```
words = {{{"w1", "w2"}, 19}, {{"w1", "w3"}, 8}, {{"w1", "w4"}, 
    7}, {{"w2", "w5"}, 7}, {{"w2", "w5"}, 7}, {{"w3", "w6"}, 
    7}, {{"w3", "w7"}, 7}, {{"w3", "w8"}, 6}, {{"w4", "w6"}, 6}};

keys = {"w2", "w4", "w8"};

Select[words, ! DisjointQ[keys, First@#] &]

Pick[words, AnyTrue[MemberQ[#, Alternatives @@ keys] &] /@ words]

Select[AnyTrue[MemberQ[#, Alternatives @@ keys] &]][words]

Pick[words, IntersectingQ[keys, First@# ] & /@ words]
```

> {{{"w1", "w2"}, 19}, {{"w1", "w4"}, 7}, {{"w2", "w5"},    7}, {{"w2",
> "w5"}, 7}, {{"w3", "w8"}, 6}, {{"w4", "w6"}, 6}}